# How to change Block Controls Icon in Gutenberg?

Tags: block-editor

[image]

I want to change this icon to something custom. I have established how to create a custom block controls bar, but not sure how to change the icon.

`import {BlockControls} from "@wordpress/block-editor";`

Answer (score 2):

There is a controls prop you can use which is an object. It goes inside. Controls has an icon key which takes a string which corresponds to a Dashicon slug.

```
<BLockControls
    controls={[
    icon=”wordpress”
    title=__("Test", "gutenberg-examples"),
    onClick: () => { doSomething },
    isActive: false

    
    ]}
/>
```